# Dynamically Remove Tabs in Android

Tags: java, android

I have searched for this solution but could find anything useful, Can Anyone plz tell me can i remove a particular tab/TabSpec from a TabHost. I am making  objects for each tabSpec and saving it in arrayList. Here's the code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();
    final ArrayList<TabHost.TabSpec> list = new ArrayList<TabHost.TabSpec>();
            TabHost.TabSpec spec= tabs.newTabSpec("buttontab");
    spec.setContent(R.id.buttontab);
    spec.setIndicator("Button");
    tabs.addTab(spec);
    list.add(spec);
    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

    Button btn=(Button)tabs.getCurrentView().findViewById(R.id.buttontab);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View view) {
            TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");
            spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            return(new AnalogClock(Main.this));
        }
    });
    spec.setIndicator("Clock");
    tabs.addTab(spec);
    list.add(spec);
    }
});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to achieve that

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().removeView(tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3));
```

and to get the tab number, use `tabHost.getCurrentTab()`

Comment: helpful, but can you also tell me how do i dynamically figure out at which tab i am currently at?  That's will complete solve my issue

Comment: I have told you in the question, use tabHost.getCurrentTab() .. You can either use it in a logcat or toastmessage to know. Please rate it up if it is helpful